# jquery SmartMenus conflict?

Tags: javascript

I believe I've got a jquery conflict, but for the life of me I can't find it.
I admit, I'm not the best with jquery.

I'm using D7 with jquery update (7.x-2.3+6-dev) and I'm trying to get the jquery based SmartMenus to work: http://www.smartmenus.org/

For the most part I've got it installed and working, but the problem I'm having is that the drop down menus will not close when I mouse off them.

The menu can be seen here:
http://www.multibrand.visionmix.us/

I'm not sure what other kind of information to post, so please let me know and I'll add it.
I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I got it, I was calling a tag not specific enough.

Once I replaced:

```
$('#mainnav ul.menu').smartmenus();
$('#main-menu').smartmenus('menuHideAll');
```

with

```
$('#mainnav ul.menu:first').smartmenus();
```

Everything was fine.